# Sort and binary search or just linear search?

Tags: sorting, complexity-theory, time-complexity, binary-search, selection-sort

**Problem**

The time complexity of a selection sort is `n*(n-1)/2`. Given a list of 1000 items, how many worst case searches using linear search must be needed before it is faster to sort and use binary search?

**Attempt at solution**

The time complexity of a binary search is `floor(log(n)/log(2)+1)`. Hence the time complexity of one selection sort followed by `x` binary searches is `n*(n-1)/2+x*floor(log(n)/log(2)+1)`. The time complexity of a linear search is `n`, therefore the time complexity of `x` linear searches is `x*n`.

Thus we establish the equality `x*n=n*(n-1)/2+x*floor(log(n)/log(2)+1)`, which for `n=1000` yields `x=5550/11` and hence `floor(x)=floor(5550/11)=504`. Is this correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're trying for a lot more precision than you can get from simple number of operations. To get an *exact* number, you'd need to account for things like the processor cache (linear search probably uses it a little better).

To get a *general* idea, however, we can look at big-O complexity. The (expected) complexity of the sort is O(N log N). The complexity of a binary search is O(log N), so the complexity of M binary searches is O(M log N). Overall complexity of sorting then binary searching is approximately O((N+M) log N).

For linear search, the complexity of one search is O(N), so the complexity of M searches is O(NM).

So, for N = 1000, the break-even point should be apprxoimately:

(1000+M) * log<sub>2</sub>(1000) = 1000 M.

That's approximately: (1000+M) * 10 = 1000 M.

If we cancel the constants and divide, we get: 1000+M = 100M, then: (1000+M)/100 = M

Distributing, we get: 1000/100 + M/100 = M

Subtracting, then dividing the constants, gets to: 10 = .99M

Dividing, we get essentially M = 10.

So, ignoring differences in constant factors, our break-even point *should* be around 10 searches.

On a real CPU, I'd *guess* most of those constant factors (branch prediction, cache usage, etc.) tend to favor linear searching over binary searching to some degree (i.e., a linear search works nicely with a cache and its branches are highly predictable), so we'd expect to see a linear search remain faster than binary search up to somewhat more searches than that--probably to at least 20 searches, and quite possibly as many as 50 or 100.

There's probably one other factor to consider though. For 1000 items, a Shell-Metzner sort, with roughly O(N<sup>1.2</sup>) complexity might *very* well end up somewhat faster than a Quicksort. In my experience, it often is up to around 1500-2000 items. That's, if anything, even more difficult to estimate with any real accuracy though, so I'm just going to guess that there's a good chance it'll reduce the break-even point a little bit.